# Dynamic resize iframe in FullCalendar

Tags: iframe, resize, fullcalendar

I have Fullcalendar opening in iframe. I have a script from dyn-web.com on parent page that resizes Iframe and this works fine most of the time:

```js
function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument ? ifrm.contentDocument : ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; 
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 5+"px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

When I open the calendar initially it resizes fine, but when I select another month that has a longer page render, it will not resize.

How can I invoke the resize on the parent window?

This is the start of my calendar but I cannot figure out the syntax to dynamically call resize. I have played with the height parameter, but it needs to be dynamic:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    month: <%=monthStart%>, 
    year: <%=yearStart%>,
    eventSources: 
    [
        { url: <%=esource%>,
          type: 'GET',
          error: function() {
              alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            }  
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    month: <%=monthStart%>, 
    year: <%=yearStart%>,
    eventSources: 
    [
    { url: <%=esource%>,
      type: 'GET',
      error: function() {
      alert('there was an error while fetching events! ');
      }      
    },
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
      parent.setIframeHeight(iframeId) ;
    },
```

The `viewDisplay` handler is called every time the month/week/day view is changed. You can also use the windowResize handler to capture an event fired after the resize has actually taken place.